# How to divide WebRTC by muaz-khan chat out-put into two columns?

Tags: webrtc

I'm newbie in using `WebRTC` and I am using this [git](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection) project by Muaz-khan. I have problem when divided chat output into two columns (User name 1 and User name 2), this is default of chat output

id of this div is #chat-output

[image: id of this div is #chat-output]

Answer (score 0):

Can you show code for example? I think you just create two html containers (left and rigth for example) and push messages first to the left, and messages from the second to the right.

Comment: you need just add css stules in html. <div id="usename1" style="float: left"><div id="usename2" style="float: rigth"> . I writfe on my phone, sorry :)

Comment: thanks but I think you did not work on it before :))

Answer (score 0):

I am using this demo of him , [ https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/demos/TextChat%2BFileSharing.html].

Here is function that Text Message Out Put will put here in  . I want to change it in two columns, such as for User name 1 : `<div id="usename1"></div>`, for user name 2 : `<div id="username2"></div>`

```
document.getElementById('input-text-chat').onkeyup = function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
                // removing trailing/leading whitespace
                this.value = this.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
                if (!this.value.length) return;
                connection.send(this.value);
                appendDIV(this.value);
                this.value = '';
            };
            var chatContainer = document.querySelector('.chat-output');
            function appendDIV(event) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = event.data || event;
                chatContainer.insertBefore(div, chatContainer.firstChild);
                div.tabIndex = 0;
                div.focus();
                document.getElementById('input-text-chat').focus();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify function `appendDIV()`.

```js
function appendDIV(event) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = event.data || event;
    chatContainer.insertBefore(div, chatContainer.firstChild);
    div.tabIndex = 0;
    div.style.width = '100%';

    if (event.data)
        div.style.textAlign = 'left';
    else
        div.style.textAlign = 'right';

    div.focus();

    document.getElementById('input-text-chat').focus();
}
```

P.S. I apologize for the late reply :)